# How much hash power do I need to be able to get transaction fees?

Tags: transaction-fees

or how exactly do I get transactions fees? Can I get transactions fees as a solo miner?

Answer (score 2):

Transaction fees are part of the block reward, so if you want to get the transaction fees for a block, you must be the person to mine the block. Anyone can mine a block, and even quickly if they get extremely lucky. However, as a solo miner, unless you have invested in millions of dollars of ASIC miners to get a non-negligible percentage of the network hashrate, you likely won't be mining a block in your lifetime, or even in the lifetime of the universe.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if I start a pool, how much easier it is to mine a block? is there a way to calculate how much time I need to mine a block?

Comment: Start a pool or join a pool?

Comment: If you start a pool, it does not magically become "easier" to mine a block. If no one joins your pool, your hashrate will not increase and you will still not be able to find a block. If you join a pool, you won't get the full block reward or transaction fees.